# bazel query to list targets dependent on file

Tags: bazel, bazel-query

Given a file name, I would like to determine all `*_test` rules which depend on that file.

Is there any way to query this information from Bazel, either through `bazel query` or through some other means?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`bazel query 'rdeps(tests(//...), //build_tests:gflags.cc)'`. `tests(//...)` gives you all the `*_test` rules, and `rdeps` gives you reverse dependencies of its second argument within the first argument.

Comment: Unfortunately, `rdeps` also includes, e.g., the compiler from the toolchain

Comment: `rdeps` only returns things within its first argument that depend on things in its second argument. `tests(//...)` shouldn't include anything from the toolchain.

Comment: Hm... I might be running into the issues described in https://docs.google.com/document/d/1x-RqFFEcGIzVgtYHIq6s6Qt4vYtJWz3nuHIuqeI89dU/edit